# Keep Drawer open when navigating in React Navigation 5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-drawer

Is there a way to prevent the drawer from closing when a navigation link is clicked in [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/)? I want the user to be able to click a link in the navigation drawer, see that the screen has changed in the background (& if they swipe away from the drawer, they see the new screen), however the drawer does not close unless they manually swipe away.